# Confusion in Run a System Command and Get Output From Console

Tags: c

Here I got one program from somewhere to read output of a system call from the console.
But to fetch error messages I used `2>&1` in `fp = popen("ping 4.2.2.2 2>&1", "r");` this line instead of `fp = popen("ping 4.2.2.2", "r");`

So could anybody explain me Whats the significant of `2>&1` in above line.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[1035];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("ping 4.2.2.2 2>&1", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit;
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `2>&1` redirects the `stderr` output to `stdout`, so the messages to the error stream are received in the standard output stream. If you are running this on a console, generally `stderr` & `stdout` both output to the console.

Comment: means using 2>&1 we can convert error messages to stdout messages?

Comment: @user1089679 no convert..it means we redirect output of stderr to stdout

Comment: Not convert, it redirects. There are separate streams for input, output & error. If you want to print error message, it is generally printed onto `stderr` (like in case of `fprintf`). If you redirect, such messages are also seen on `stdout`. To see this effect, change `ping 4.2.2.2` to say `ping 344.2.2.2` which is error. Now run the program as `./a.out 2>/dev/null`. Now try out with & without `2>&1`, you will see the effect to using `2>&1` & not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0=stdin` ; `1=stdout` ; `2=stderr`

If you do `2>1` that will redirect all the `stderr` to a file named `1`. To actually redirect `stderr` to `stdout` you need to use `2>&1`. `&1` means passing the handle to the `stdout`.

This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21) in detail.